# How can i change a .properties file into an XML file?

Tags: java, xml, tfs, properties

How can i change a .properties file into an XML file?

I have developed an automation framework which reads a central config file which is of type .properties file. My framework uses the Java programming language and i need a way to alter the values contained within the .properties file via MS TFS.

I know that within MS TFS you can create global variables and then feed the information / data to an xml file, is there a way to change a .properties file into an XML file and in turn also read those values within my JAVA framework?

**Example Java code which reads the .properties file:**

```
public WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
    try {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(Base_Page.getConstant(Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY));
        p.load(fi);

        String browserName = p.getProperty("browser");
        switch (browserName) {
```

**Properties file:**

[image]

[This link](http://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/DevOps/replace-appsettings-token-configfiles-build-release-tfs-vsts) instructs you how to alter values stored within the TFS using an XML file.

Comment: You can load the properties-file and save it as a xml-file with [`Properties.storeToXML(OutputStream os,
              String comment)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML-based property file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
  <comment>Your comment here</comment>
  <entry key="your.property.key">Your property value</entry>
  <entry key="your.second.property.key">Your second property value</entry>
</properties>
```

You can store them with [`Properties.storeToXML​(OutputStream os, String comment)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-) and load them with [`Properties.loadFromXML​(InputStream in)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML-java.io.InputStream-):

Comment: thanks for you help! would  i need to change the Java code which reads the .properties file?